# to get array format if convert json code in php

Tags: php

**I want to convert my file into json decode.After that I want to get with array format.If I change to array ,output is Array[0]=>null.How can I do that?**
**This is my file**

```
{
  "status": "1",
  "mobile_user": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "saa",
      "phone_no": "09978784963",
      "activate_code": "",
      "deposit": "0",
      "created": "2015-05-29 00:00:00",
      "updated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "status": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "ttr",
      "phone_no": "090930499",
      "activate_code": "",
      "deposit": "0",
      "created": "2015-06-01 00`:00:00",
      "updated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "status": "0"
    },.....
```

**This is my code**

```
 <?php
   include "connect.php"; 
    $data =      file_get_contents("http://192.168.0.100/busexpress/api/v1/mobile_user_register/mobile_user_register/retrieve.json");

$json =array(json_decode($data, true));
 print_r ($json);      

    ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the $data is getting? Try printing that first.

Comment: Json code is valid.I'm testing it in jsonlint.com.

Comment: can you please do a var_dump($data) and post the results?

Comment: var_dump($data).The result is 'NULL'.

Comment: If your return value is NULL, is json_decode return value ( error) Check your string.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Check your file permission to read the json file since data is getting as NULL. The problem is not in your code I guess.

Answer (score -1):

i tried your code, I think the remote file is not responding. Here is what I got. otherwise the code looks fine to me.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://192.168.0.100/busexpress/api/v1/mobile_user_register/mobile_user_register/retrieve.json): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Array ( [0] => )

Comment: You are trying to access something on his internal network. Of course it will not work unless you are on the same LAN as him.

Comment: The code should work in that case. BTW he has given the second argument as "true" already. So better read question first and then comment.